# Magento product view observer not raised

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I'm trying to develop a module to create a log for each product visited by a user.
To generate a log, I'm using event observer. But the event never is called.

What could be wrong?
My code:
C:\Users\miudo\AppData\Local\Temp\scp44107\home\sr\localhos.t\app\code\local\Bit\Itemsviewed\Model\Observer.php

```
<?php
class Bit_Itemsviewed_Model_Observer 
{
    public function saveProductVisitHistory(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();

        Mage::log('id ' . $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getId() , null, 'custom.log');

        return $this;
    }
}
```

C:\Users\miudo\AppData\Local\Temp\scp47708\home\sr\localhos.t\app\code\local\Bit\Itemsviewed\etc\Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Bit_Itemsviewed>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Bit_Itemsviewed>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
          <itemsviewed>
            <class>Bit_Itemsviewed_Helper</class>
          </itemsviewed>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
          <itemsviewed>
            <class>Bit_Itemsviewed_Block</class>
          </itemsviewed>
        </blocks>       
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_view>Bit_Itemsviewed_Block_Itemsviewed</product_view>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
        <models>
            <itemsviewed>
                <class>Bit_Itemsviewed_Model</class>        
            </itemsviewed>
        </models>
    <!--/global>
    <frontend-->
        <events>
            <catalog_controller_product_view>
                <observers>
                    <itemsviewed>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>bit_itemsviewed/observer</class>
                        <method>saveProductVisitHistory</method>
                    </itemsviewed>
                </observers>
            </catalog_controller_product_view>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

C:\Users\miudo\AppData\Local\Temp\scp57676\home\sr\localhos.t\app\code\local\Bit\Itemsviewed\Helper\Data.php

```
<?php
class Bit_Itemsviewed_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{
}
```

C:\Users\miudo\AppData\Local\Temp\scp48515\home\sr\localhos.t\app\code\local\Bit\Itemsviewed\Block\Itemsviewed.php

```
<?php
class Bit_Itemsviewed_Block_Itemsviewed extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View{
}
```

Thanks

EDITED:
I had been trying to use

```
<itemsviewed>
  <type>model</type> also <singleton>
  <class>itemsviewed/observer</class> also <class> Bit_Itemsviewed_Model_Observer </class>
 [...]
</itemsviewed>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring your models under the shortname/namespace `itemsviewed`, but when you declare your event observer you are using `bit_itemsviewed`. It should therefore be:

```
<class>itemsviewed/observer</class>
```

Comment: Already try your suggestion.. but not worked...

Comment: Ah.. and thanks Amit and Cags, now I understand the syntax needed in events xml structure.

Answer (score 1):

D Millar try this event

`catalog_controller_product_init_after` instead of  `catalog_controller_product_view` event .

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_controller_product_init_after',
    array('product' => $product,
        'controller_action' => $controller
    )
```

### **for Observer code is look like:**

```
<?php
class Bit_Itemsviewed_Model_Observer 
{
    public function saveProductVisitHistory(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $product=$event->getProduct()
        $controller_action=$event->getControllerAction()
        Mage::log('id ' . $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getId() , null, 'custom.log');

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Also as Cags said you need to change you class of observer from `bit_itemsviewed/observer` to `itemsviewd` as Your model  identifier is <`itemsviewed`> because of

```
 <models>
    <itemsviewed>  <!-- model indentifier -->
        <class>Bit_Itemsviewed_Model</class>        
    </itemsviewed>
</models>
```

Comment: Still not working. But I'm beginning to think that my solution will not work.
I believe, that when a product is visited, this log should be created in a block, and not using an observer. It will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Use this example to make it work, as I just tested it:

```
<frontend>
<events>
   <catalog_controller_product_init_after>
            <observers>
                <gtm_see_product_details>
                    <class>gtm/observer</class>
                    <method>setGTMSeeProductDetails</method>
                </gtm_see_product_details>
            </observers>
        </catalog_controller_product_init_after>
...
```

path: app\code\local\OsfMinitrade\GTM\etc\config.xml

```
/**
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 * @return Varien_Event_Observer
 */
public function setGTMSeeProductDetails(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    var_dump($observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getId());
    die;

    return $observer;
}
```

path: app\code\local\OsfMinitrade\GTM\Model\Observer.php